# Why can't I add an object to the database? (mvc3)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, addition

It's quite a simple question: When someone click on "Edit Plan" in my ASP.NET MVC project - He doesn't edit but create a new plan with. You can see it more clearly in my answer to my qeustion here: [How do I duplicate an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225985/how-do-i-duplicate-an-object)

Now I want to do the same thing to its references,  and I did it like that:

```
var featurePlans = db.FeaturePlanBaseSet.Where(f => f.PlanId == plan.Id).ToList();

db.PlanSet.AddObject(plan);
db.SaveChanges();

for (var i = 0; i < featurePlans.Count(); i++ )
{
   featurePlans[i].Plan = plan;
   db.FeaturePlanBaseSet.AddObject(featurePlans[i]);
}
```

Plan is added when I do `AddObject`, but `Feature` isn't.

I get this error:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The existing object is in the Unchanged state.

I'll be glad to know why does it happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not appear that you save after adding FeaturePlanBaseSet.  You need to call `db.SaveChanges()` last to save all changes.

EDIT: It also appears that you are reading an existing FeaturePlanBaseSet record from the database and then adding that record back.  The next line will retrieve an existing record.

```
var featurePlans = db.FeaturePlanBaseSet.Where(f => f.PlanId == plan.Id).ToList();
```

When you add `featurePlans[i]`, you are adding the existing record. If you plan to add a new record, Do it as follows:

```
for (var i = 0; i < featurePlans.Count(); i++ ) 
{ 
   var featurePlan = new FeaturePlanBaseSet();
   featurePlan.Plan = plan; 
   ...set other properties
   db.FeaturePlanBaseSet.AddObject(featurePlan); 
}
```